# sql: have an aggregate repeat over the excess rows of a returned result so I can do calculations with it in each row

Tags: sql

What I want to do is I have one column grouped up, I want to compare it to a column that's similar but aggregate so only one row in that column.  I want to compare the aggregate row to every row in the grouping.  My thinking is something like this but maybe there's a better way?

```
select CustomerID, count(OrderID), count(OrderID)/TotalOrders from Order_T 
full outer join (select count(OrderID) TotalOrders from Order_T)
group by CustomerID;
```

I'm sure this won't run the way it is but I just want to show my train of thought.  I want the number of orders of a particular customer divided by the total number of orders in the table.  The percentage the customer represents in orders.  Can this be done in one statement?  Probably in a totally different way than I'm thinking.

Comment: Yes cross apply , full outer join is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to simply introduce the total count as a subquery in the select statement. This is written using T-SQL syntax for SQL Server, but except for the cast it should be generic SQL.

```
select 
    CustomerID, 
    count(OrderID), 
    count(OrderID) / cast( (select count(OrderID) TotalOrders 
                            from Order_T) as decimal(10,3)
                         ) 
from Order_T 
group by CustomerID
```

I added the cast to decimal in case the counts are integers so that fractions won't be lost. The odd formatting was just for readability.

Comment: thanks for the help.  It's late now but Ill definitely be trying this tomorrow.

Comment: this is actually much simpler than what I was thinking,  SQL is smarter than I thought.